# Why ZooKeeper needs to usleep in order to create persistent nodes

Tags: c++, apache-zookeeper

I want to create persistent nodes in ZooKeeper. To do this, I have these two functions:

```
void create_completion(int rc, const char * value, const void * data){
    // empty callback at this moment
}
void create(const char * path, const char * value){
    zoo_acreate(zh, path, value, 0, &ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, 0, create_completion, NULL);
}
```

What I find interesting, is that if I call `create` function from my `main` function and then just terminate, then no data is uploaded:

```
int main(){
    ... some code to initialize session
    create("/newnode", ""); // node is not created
    zookeeper_close(zh);
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas if I do:

```
int main(){
    ... some code to initialize session
    create("/newnode", ""); // node is created
    bool flag = true;
    while(flag){
        usleep(10000000);
        flag = false;
    }
    zookeeper_close(zh);
    return 0;
}
```

then `"/newnode"` is uploaded to `ZooKeeper`. So, what is wrong with that and why do I really need this loop?

Comment: I don't know much about zookeeper, but I read it has a sync and an async api. Which one do you use?

Comment: Or, I think I get what you mean. The program may terminate before the async call completes.

Comment: It looks like you can use `zoo_aget` to wait for completion of an async request. Maybe you can use that instead of the sleep.

Comment: Well, obviously if you use an asynchronous interface, you still need to block in the completion of the operation...

Comment: Thank you, guys. The problem was that I had not delt with async functions in C++ prior to that and in tutorials there were large examples which I think worked because of their sophisticated logic and some blocks. Unfortunatelly, the authors of the examples do not stress this very important fact - that if you write a teeny-weeny example and use async api, make sure that your program does not terminate before callbacks complete